# Is it possible to disable nether in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to build a custom map, and I don't want people to be entering nether if someone would build a portal.

With only command blocks or just commands, is it be possible for the nether portal not teleport you anywhere, teleport you a few blocks away from it, or just teleport you back into the map's center? (In singleplayer)

Comment: I assume survival, and 1.8, right?

Comment: Well, the player who is playing the map, is going to be in survival, yes.
And the map is going to be in 1.9, but I assume 1.8 solutions might also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, have a repeating command block set to `Always Active` testing for a `minecraft:portal` block(the purple part of the nether portal):

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:portal
```

It will point into another repeating command block, also `Always Active`, and it will also be set to `Conditional`, using `/spreadplayers` to teleport them 2-4 blocks out of the portal.

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ spreadplayers ~ ~ 2 4 true @p
```

The reason `/execute` is used is to teleport them within a 2-4 block range of where they are currently.

Comment: Whoops, I typed `/execute @p ~ ~ ~ spreadplayers ~ ~ 2 4 true` wrong. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of changed the second command into teleporting a player into map's center, because for some reason the spreadplayers command didn't work.

Comment: Yea, I changed it wrong again, lol. The correct command is `/execute @p ~ ~ ~ spreadplayers ~ ~ 2 4 true @p`. But your way works too!

Comment: `@p` will not work for multiplayer, since it only targets the player closest to the command block. Use `@a` and `@a[c=1]` in the execute and subsequent commands, respectively, instead.

Comment: Also, you can condense this to a single command by using execute's `detect` scheme instead of testforblock: `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecrat:portal -1 spreadplayers ~ ~ 2 4 true @a[c=1]`.